# расположить элементы разной ширины по центру

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно используя один CSS расположить большие элементы по центру. Ширина конечно же заранее неизвестна. Также нужно чтобы элементы не растягивались. При большом размере экрана/монитора/браузера слева добавлялась пустота, а при маленьком мониторе эти элементы не занимали лишнее место по бокам. вот как на картинке.

```
.centered{ 

/*margin-left:20%;*/ 


width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

пробовал так, но оно всегда добавляет пустое место слева даже на укзком мониторе. приходится крутить линию прокрутки снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то

Таблицу оберните в элемент с `display: inline-block;`

Родителю этой обертки добавьте `text-align: center;`

Comment: Это почти то что нужно - таблицы , заголовки отображаются по центру страницы теперь, но у меня поехали сами ячейки. Т.е. содержимое ячеек теперь привязано не к левому краю таблиц и к центру. Обновил вопрос

Comment: В таком случае верните обратно выравнивание по левому краю для контента, добавив text-align: left; к обертке

Comment: Если и так плохо, то вместо left выставьте initial )

Comment: решил проблему добавив каждой вложенно таблице `text-align: left;` Большое спасибо.